# pass array to $location.search in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, url, url-parameters

I have an array of user ids. I want to pass user ids to $location.search

```
$scope.userIds = [1, 2];
$location.search({'userId[]' : $scope.userIds}).path('/search');
```

It give a URL

> /search?userId%5B%5D=1&userId%5B%5D=2

if I remove %5B%5D unwanted chars then it works

How to remove them?

Comment: I think I asked wrong question. It is working with $location.search but see updated answer

Comment: Try removing the "[ ]" like so: $location.search({'userId': $scope.userIds}).path('/search')

Comment: Previously was not working :O  Now worked :'D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate the unwanted characters Try removing the "[ ]" like so:

```
$location.search({'userId': $scope.userIds}).path('/search')
```

hope it helps